# What caused the following aggregate initialization problem?

Tags: c++

I am trying to reproduce the code explained in a textbook about learning c++. The simplest one is given as follows. But it does not compile as expected.

```
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct Storage
{
 vector<int> data;
};

Storage GetStorage(vector<int> params)
{
    return Storage{ .data=params};
}
```

Intellisense gives me this error back:

```
Storege{(<error-type>)<error-constant>}
expected an expression C/C++(29)
```

Comment: `Storage` is not an aggregate.

Comment: @Brian: Could you elaborate more about it? I don't understand why `Storage` is not an aggregate.

Comment: You may want to read [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).

Comment: @Brian: That link clearly explains why `Storage` _is_ an aggregate.

Comment: Can you remove the image and post text, please?

Comment: @Peter Gah, so it is. For some reason I was thinking aggregates had to be trivial. That's what I get for commenting before the coffee kicks in. I'll leave my comments as they are in case they help someone else learn from my confusion.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Why? The image size is too small.

Comment: Images cannot be indexed, serached by their content or be read by screen readers used by visually impared folks.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: It does make sense. Thank you!

Comment: @MoneySetsYouFree [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/wh-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The most appropriate reason not to upload image is "every time an image of code is uploaded, a kitten somewhere dies.". Unfortunately, I uploaded an error message that none wants to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set your language version to C++20 for designated initializers to work. On visual studio you must enable the flag `/std:c++latest` and `-std=c++20` on other compilers

Comment: Does this actually fix the issue? I thought C++20's designated initializers only applied to aggregates.

Comment: @Brian it is an aggregate